# How can I replace string values in a pandas frame

Tags: pandas

In a pandas frame with 4 columns, I need to remove the digits from the end of the names of the Country column that have them:

```
                                        Country        Energy
56                     Central African Republic            23   
57                                         Chad            77   
58                                        Chile          1613   
59                                       China2        127191   
60                                    Hong Kong           585
75                                     Denmark5           725
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a function to remove digits at the end of the string and apply it to that specific column:

```
import pandas as pd
import string

def remove_digits(country):
    return country.rstrip(string.digits)

df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['China2', 'Hong Kong'], 'energy': [127191, 585]})
print(df)
df['country'] = df['country'].apply(remove_digits)
print('\n', df)
```

This will return:

```
     country  energy
0     China2  127191
1  Hong Kong     585

      country  energy
0      China  127191
1  Hong Kong     585
```

Comment: Could simply use `df["country"].str.rstrip("0123456789")` instead of applying.

Answer (score 0):

Most simply, I'd use regex to replace digits at the end with an empty string:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['China2', 'Hong Kong', 'Ireland43'], 'energy': [127191, 585, 999]})
print(df)
df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace('[0-9]?', '', regex=True)
print('\n', df)
```

This returns:

```
     Country  energy
0     China2  127191
1  Hong Kong     585
2  Ireland43     999

      Country  energy
0      China  127191
1  Hong Kong     585
2    Ireland     999
```